# Error: Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [Agenda]' (aka 'inout Array<Agenda>')

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am making an app of which when you press a button saying it's urgent, there is a label saying "URGENT." Just before I implement the user interaction with the button, I have an array (like below) with some objects having `urgent = true`, but some having `urgent = false`, so I can start out with my code.

The array, which is in `MainTableViewController.swift`:

```
var content:[Agenda] = [
    Agenda(subject: "Read this article", deadline: "1-2 days", urgent: false),
    Agenda(subject: "Respond to this email", deadline: "ASAP", urgent: true),
    Agenda(subject: "Add this to diary", deadline: "When at home", urgent: true),
    Agenda(subject: "Listen to this song", deadline: "When finished working", urgent: false),
    Agenda(subject: "Check out this holiday destination", deadline: "At the weekend", urgent: false),
    Agenda(subject: "Download this podcast", deadline: "1-4 days", urgent: false),
    Agenda(subject: "Update notes", deadline: "When at home", urgent: true)
]
```

Then, I have a class called `Agenda.swift` where I declare the `subject`, `deadline`, and `urgent`.

Here is the code where I show the "URGENT" or not:

```
if content[indexPath.row].urgent = true {
        cell.urgentLabel.text = "URGENT"
    } else {
        cell.urgentLabel.text = ""
    }
```

On the first line, I get the following error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [Agenda]' (aka 'inout Array')

Comment: `if content[indexPath.row].urgent = true {` should just be `if content[indexPath.row].urgent {`

Comment: or == instead of = (assignment statement return nothing in Swift)

Comment: @VinceBurn Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the classic assignment operator (`=`) vs. equation operator (`==`) confusion.

Comment: my solution for this error was that i needed to cast an Int to a String

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use `+=` of all things!

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this same error when I was subscripting an array as an argument value to a method which had an incorrect signature. That is, one of the argument labels was wrong but the compiler reported the error as an inability to subscript the array. Once I pulled the array access out of the method call, the true error was revealed.

Answer (score 1):

As partially explained in the comments, this line

```
if content[indexPath.row].urgent = true {
```

is attempting to set the value of urgent, not check the value of urgent.

If you want to use that pattern, you simply need to add an additional = sign

```
if content[indexPath.row].urgent == true {
```

also, an if statement will evaluate a boolean value directly so you don't even need the comparison

```
if content[indexPath.row].urgent {
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift3 problems: I had a dictionary which didn't have

```
 as [String:Any]
```

in the end, so the compiler told me I cannot subscript an inout object. Added that in the end and boom, solved.